# How to run jsdoc on whole directory in ubuntu

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I just need to run jsdoc on ai whole directory containing .js files, I am doing this on individual files in ubuntu terminal by issuing command jsdoc abc.js but what I need is to apply this command on all files in the directory at once,so that all files in that directory containg js files would be generated by a single command. Thanks for any help you would give.

Answer (score 27):

You can go recursive by passing **-r** parameter:

```
$ jsdoc -r .
```

Comment: Recurse into subdirectories when scanning for source files and tutorials.
[Source](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html)

Answer (score 6):

Even though it's only asked how to run JSDoc for a specific directory, I think this thread could use some more information so people reading this can be aware of other strategies that could be useful.

## Running JSDoc for a specific directory

This is the simplest one and the direct answer to the question. You can run JSDoc for all files inside a directory using the `--recurse` or `-r` option.

Example:

```
$ jsdoc -r ./src/
```

This will run JSDoc for all files inside the `src/` directory and its subdirectories.

## Running JSDoc for multiple directories

This and the following sections aren't exactly what the question asked for but hopefully will be useful for people using a search engine that found this thread.

You'll probably need to run JSDoc for all the files located in different directories. For this you can just use multiple arguments with the `--recurse` option.

Example:

```
$ jsdoc -r ./client/ ./server/
```

This will run JSDoc for all files inside both `client/` and `server/` and its subdirectories.

## NOT running JSDoc for some directories

This is slightly more complicated and will require use of JSDoc's configuration file. After creating the configuration file, you can run JSDoc using the `--configure` (or `-c`) option to select the configuration file you want to use.

Example:
Create a file `conf.json` as shown bellow:

```json
{
    "source": {
        "include": [ "." ],
        "exclude": [ "node_modules/" ]
    }
}
```

Then run JSDoc like that:

```
jsdoc -c ./conf.json -r
```

With that JSDoc will be run for all files inside your current directory and its subdirectories except for the ones located inside `node_modules/` and its subdirectories.

### Sources

For more info on the available options for the `jsdoc` command see [here](https://jsdoc.app/about-commandline.html)

For more info on the JSDoc configuration file see [here](https://jsdoc.app/about-configuring-jsdoc.html)